# Can't seem to return all values in database for displaying

Tags: php

I created a simple upvote system for my website, I have a little bug where it will not grab all of the ID's that I need for displaying. The issue is that I have multiple repeat values in the database for the ID of each item that the user's voted on.
I created a separate table for the votes so that I can update the arrow color when it has been voted.

Here is the code for displaying the results, it's in a foreach loop:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){ 
    if(($row['voteLikes_topic'] == $row['topic_id']) && ($row['voteLikes_user'] == $_SESSION['user_session'])){
        var_dump($row['voteLikes_topic']);
        $returnValues .=    '<a href="#" id="upVoteColorChangeID'.$row['topic_id'].'" class="upVoteArrow fullClickLink" style="color:#bd2204;" onclick="upVoteIncrementValue('.$row['topic_id'].');"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a> ';  
    }else{
        $returnValues .=    '<a href="#" id="upVoteColorChangeID'.$row['topic_id'].'" class="upVoteArrow fullClickLink" onclick="upVoteIncrementValue('.$row['topic_id'].');"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a> ';
    }
}
```

Here are the columns in the database for the voting results:

[image]

Here is the query:

```
 $query = "SELECT       
        count(replies.reply_topic) as replyCount,
        topics.topic_id,
        topics.topic_subject,
        topics.topic_date,
        topics.topic_cat,
        topics.topic_picture,
        topics.topic_creator,
        topics.topic_likes,
        users.user_id,
        users.username,
        profile.profile_id,
        profile.profile_pictureMain,
        profile.profile_users,
        savelink.saveLink_id,
        savelink.saveUser_id,
        savelink.link_id,
        votelikes.voteLikes_user,
        votelikes.voteLikes_topic,
        votelikes.voteLikes_hot,
        votelikes.voteLikes_cold
        FROM
            topics
        LEFT JOIN
            users
        ON
            topics.topic_creator = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            replies
        ON
            replies.reply_topic = topics.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
            profile
        ON
            profile.profile_users = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            savelink
        ON
            savelink.link_id = topics.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
            votelikes
        ON
            votelikes.voteLikes_topic = topics.topic_id
        GROUP BY
            topics.topic_id
        ORDER BY
            topics.topic_date DESC 
        LIMIT ?, ?
        ";
```

And here is what the query is displaying (for clarity)

[image]

So what is happening right now is that once it grabs the 'voteLikes_topic' value of say 66 for the 'voteLikes_user' ID of 41 then if I log in with voteLikes_user ID of 6 and it also has a value in the column of voteLikes_topic 66, it won't display the second value in the database.

Simply put: since 'voteLikes_topic' value of '66' came first with 'voteLikes_user' value of '41', then the voteLikes_topic value of 66 won't display for voteLikes_user value of 6.

I know it's a simple query problem but I am not finding it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point of the `$row['voteLikes_topic'] == $row['topic_id']` part of the condition? Please describe what all these columns represent. Also please show your SQL query while you're at it.

Comment: @Jeto the $row['voteLikes_topic'] == $row['topic_id'] is so that I can grab the values of the row that coincide with the item that was upvoted.